# error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token cast issue

Tags: c++, c, struct, malloc

I'm trying to figure out why I get a compile error (in the title of this message) for this cast during the initialization of a struct member variable.

in myclass.h

```
class MyClass {
    ...
    public:
        struct cpresets {
            char* soundfont_key;
            char* exists;
            UT_hash_handle hh;
        };
    ...
};
```

in myclass.cc

```
void myclass::mymethod() {
    ...
    struct cpresets *newpreset;
    newpreset = (cpresets*) malloc(sizeof( cpresets));
    ...

}
```

There is another place in the cc file where this works.

in myclass.cc

```
...
typedef struct {
    ...
}mystruct;

...

static instantiate(){
    ...
    //this line causes the compile error
    mystruct* me = (mystruct*) malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
    ...
}
```

I see the difference in the case where it works is that the struct is defined in the cc file and in the case where it doesnt work, the struct is a member vairable of the class header.  Do you know why this is an issue or what I might be able to do to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Indicate which line gives the error. The first 2 code blocks have no indication, and the third one says "this line causes the error" but the text before the third block says "this works"

Answer (score 1):

You miss the return type for `static instantiate()`, should probably be 
`static void instantiate()`

Comment: actually the semi-colon is there in the file.  I edited the example